# QTreeView: Setting all selected cells to the user-entered value at once

Tags: qt, set, qtreeview

I have a QTreeView which has the ExtendedSelection attribute (users may select more than one non-contiguous range of cells).

I would like my app to allow them to select these multiple cells and then enter a value and have all the cells take that value.

My issue is that I don't know how to get the full range of cells passed to my model.  Right now the index that is passed to the setData method is only the active cell, not the full range of selected cells.

In the past, I have had my view store the currently selected range in the model every time it changes, and then use that to control which cells to modify.  This seems kind of hacky and I wonder whether anyone has a better and more elegant solution.

I am using PyQt by the way, though I suspect this applies to QT by itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use [selectionModel](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) method of the QAbstractItemView class to iterate through selected indexes and change values of the corresponding cells. Below is a small example:

```
foreach (QModelIndex index, ui->treeView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes())
{
    qDebug() << "Changing index " << index.row();
    ui->treeView->model()->setData(index, "new data");
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: That looks like it might point me in the right direction. Thanks. One question though, where do I call this code?  Is there a signal I should be connecting to (the same one that is currently calling setData)?

Comment: yes, I believe you should be able to execute this inside your "setdata" signal. I've tested this by simply putting a pushbutton on the main window widget and calling this code from its "on_clicked" signal handler

Comment: Sorry to be dense but the setdata signal you refer to... is that a signal sent by my QTreeView? I can't find any reference to it. I do have a setData slot in the model. Is that what you are referring to? If so, I am once again stuck because it seems like the model would then need to know about the view in order to extract the selected indexes.

Comment: I was referring to whatever signal you meant by "the same one that is currently calling setData"

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what that signal is. When I set the dataModel for the QTreeView, it automatically calls setData and I am not sure what the signal is.  In any event, I am going to mark your answer as the one I am looking for because it gets me most of the way with the selectionModel.  Thanks!